# Sending php in a name value which is an html form

Tags: php, html

```
<form action='itemEdit.php' method='post' />
      <input type='hidden' name='<?php $row['id'];?>' value='' />
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Edit'                  
</form>
```

is it possible to send this php script to the 'itemEdit.php' page and put the row output into a php variable?  I've tried this and haven't had any success.  I can't figure this out by just using mySql.  Thanks

Comment: yes its possible, just put the row id into the value and give it a proper name, handle the submission and call the proper name index and get the value

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following..

```
<form action='itemEdit.php' method='post' />
      <input type='hidden' name="YouFieldNameHERE" value="<?php $row['id'];?>" />
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Edit'/>                 
</form>
```

Then in your itemEdit.php you can access it like ...

```
$fieldValue = $_POST['YouFieldNameHERE'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **name** attribute to indicate what value you are passing and either use **echo** or a **shorttag** or no value will be in the **name** attribute:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?= htmlentities($row['id']) ?>'>

<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']) ?>'>
```

If you are naming your attribute with the id, it would look like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='<?= htmlentities($row['id']) ?>' value=''>

<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']) ?>' value=''>
```

The **htmlentities** helps protect against XSS.

Also be sure to close the **submit** tag.

If it is HTML5, you don't need the **/>**

Answer (score 0):

two thing one use value for not name for input value. 
another use `echo` or `<?=` to print value in input 
instead of this

```
<input type='hidden' name='<?php $row['id'];?>' value='' />
```

use

```
 <input type='hidden' name='inputname' value='<?php echo $row['id'];?>' />
```

to get value in next page

```
echo $_POST['inputname'];
```